# memcpy function calling inside mex

Tags: c++, matlab, mex, memcpy, matrix-indexing

I have an interesting problem. Namely like that; I am trying to use std::memcpy function inside by mex function and calling that mex function inside MATLAB like that;

```
I2 = b_filter(I);
```

When I copy the whole image, it works well;

```
plhs[0] =  mxCreateDoubleMatrix(mxGetM(plhs[0]), mxGetN(plhs[0]), mxREAL);          
memcpy(mxGetPr(plhs[0]), mxGetPr(prhs[0]), sizeof(double) *mxGetM(plhs[0]) * mxGetN(plhs[0]));
```

But when I try to copy some part of image

```
plhs[0] =  mxCreateDoubleMatrix(100, 100, mxREAL);              
memcpy(mxGetPr(plhs[0]), mxGetPr(prhs[0]), sizeof(double) * 100 * 100);
```

it doesn't give right image part but gives unmeaningful pixel values.

So what is going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ha Ha! You've been caught by one of the nastiest of mex file nuances!  It's got me before too.  Arrays in mex functions are stored in column order not row order, so you:

> You still use column-first indexing like in Matlab, though

[Blog URL](http://www.shawnlankton.com/2008/03/getting-started-with-mex-a-short-tutorial/)

Try this [page](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/Matrix-Indexing-in-MATLAB/matrix.html;jsessionid=3bb34577abc47cbe7646be993606) too for a nice picture of the ordering.

[image: Figure From Mathworks]

Finally I would recommend reading [this thread](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/249954) to get a better idea behind the difference of C and MATLAB matrix memory being column-ordered.

Comment: I am gonna check it out!

Cheers!

Comment: Not only is there an ordering issue, but `memcpy` will produce and effect like `reshape`.  It certainly will not act like the MATLAB slicing operator, which seems to be what the OP desires.

Answer (score 3):

As explained by @macduff, MATLAB uses a [column-major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order#Column-major_order) to store arrays, while C arrays are row-major.

Here is a sample implementation showing how to copy part of a matrix.

#### matrix_slice_mex.c

```
#include "mex.h"
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    double *in, *out;
    mwIndex i,j;
    mwSize numRows;

    /* input checks */
    if (nrhs != 1 || nlhs > 1) {
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("MATLAB:nargchk", "Wrong number of arguments.");
    }
    if (mxGetNumberOfDimensions(prhs[0])>2 || !mxIsDouble(prhs[0])) {
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("MATLAB:wrongDims", "Expecting 2D double matrix.");
    }
    if (mxGetM(prhs[0])<100 || mxGetN(prhs[0])<100) {
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("MATLAB:wrongDims", "Matrix size must be >= 100x100.");
    }

    /* extract sub-matrix */
    plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(100, 100, mxREAL);
    out = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);
    in = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
    numRows = mxGetM(prhs[0]);
    for(j=0; j<100; j++) {
        for(i=0; i<100; i++) {
            *out++ = in[i + numRows*j];
        }
    }
}
```

And to test this:

```
x = rand(1000);
y = x(1:100,1:100);
yy = matrix_slice_mex(x);
isequal(y,yy)
```

You could have also used `memcpy` to copy each of the columns (one for-loop instead)